# Difference between prewired LEDs of different voltages

Tags: led

I'm searching for a simple prewired LED I can directly connect to a power supply. I see options of different voltages for example 3 V, 6 V, 9 V, 12 V.

Assuming I will pick the power supply according to the LED voltage, does it matter which I choose? Will higher voltage use less current?

For reference, I will use it for a dollhouse lighting.

Comment: That information will be in the data sheet; i.e. what will the nominal current be when supplied with nominal voltage. So unless you have data sheets of the parts in order to compare them, the question can't be answered if any 12V LED uses less current than a 6V LED.

Comment: I think that you are using a confusing term ... you are describing an `LED lamp with an integrated resistor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not they'll use less overall power depends on how they're wired, but typically the way it works is that the higher voltage strips split the LEDs into longer series runs.

With the lowest voltage, the strip probably looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBExcV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All the LEDs are in parallel. The forward voltage drop of each LED is a couple of volts (e.g. 2.5V) and the resistor limits the current by creating a voltage drop equivalent to the supply voltage minus that forward voltage.

For the higher voltage strips, they just add more LEDs to each parallel run. The same four LEDs above could instead be organised as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuAI76.png)</sup>

The voltage drop of the LEDs in each pair is now double that of a single LED, and again the resistor limits the current by creating a voltage drop equivalent to the difference between the sum of the voltage drops for the LED pairs and the supply voltage.

By adding more LEDs in series, the overall current drops. The power stays roughly the same, because \$P=IV\$, and you're roughly doubling the supply voltage but halving the supply current, assuming the resistor values don't change.

You can keep doing this with more and more LEDs in series for higher and higher supply voltages (and lower supply currents) up into the tens and hundreds of volts. In fact, many mains-powered LED panels simply convert the AC from the mains (110V or 230V) to rectified DC and supply that to a very long string of LEDs without any need to reduce the voltage with a regulator or switching converter.

The main trade-off here is the impact of an LED failure. In the first circuit example I showed, if one LED breaks then it is the only one that turns off. In the second example I showed, if one LED breaks then both LEDs in the pair fail, because they're in series. The more LEDs you add in series, the more LEDs will stop working if one of them breaks. But in a well-designed circuit in an unchallenging environment (i.e. not being constantly vibrated or knocked or exposed to hazardous chemicals) an LED should have a lifetime of tens of thousands of hours, so it's often not too much of a concern to use series LEDs.

Comment: I'm talking about single LED with prewired resistor, not about strips. maybe I misunderstood your answer, but I was asking what's the difference between the 3v prewired LED and the 12v. If I connect them all in parallel is there any advantage for the 3v ones?

Comment: Oh, on a single prewired LED the difference will be the resistor value, which means you'll use the same amount of current regardless of which voltage you're using, and the resistor will waste more power (as dissipated heat) on the higher voltage LEDs. So the 3V ones are your best option in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Thank you. So the LED is essentially the same, but the resistor is different, correct?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly.